# Sequentially Run Programs in Unix

Tags: unix, ksh

I have several programs that need to be ran in a certain order (p1 then p2 then p3 then p4).
Normally I would simply make a simple script or type p1 && p2 && p3 && p4.

However, these programs to not exit correctly.  I only know it is finished successfully when "Success" is printed.  Currently, I SIGINT once I see "Success" or "Fail" and then manually run the next program if it's "Success".

Is there a simpler way to sequentially execute p1, p2, p3, p4 with less human intervention?

Edit: Currently using ksh, but I wouldn't mind knowing the other ones too.

Comment: Currently using ksh, but I wouldn't mind knowing the other ones too.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can pipe the command to grep looking for 'Success', then rely on grep's result code.  The trick to that is wrapping the whole expression in curly braces to get an inline sub-shell.  Like so:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
[ 0 -eq $(( $RANDOM %2 )) ] && echo 'Success' || echo 'Failure'
exit 0

$ { ./foo.sh | grep -q 'Success'; } && ls || df
```

The part inside the curly braces (`{}`) returns 0 if "Success" is in the output, otherwise 1, as if the foo.sh command had done so itself. [More details on that technique.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127334/bash-subshell-creation-with-curly-braces)

I've not used ksh in a long while, but I suspect there is a [similar construction](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix2.1/ksh/ch08_06.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to linux programming, but I found something that might be helpful for you. Have you tried using the '[wait](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uwait.htm)' command?

from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76717/bash-launch-background-process-and-check-when-it-ends) on stackexchange:

```
sleep 1 &
PID1=$!
sleep 2 &
PID2=$!

wait $PID1
echo PID1 has ended.
wait
echo All background processes have exited.
```

I haven't tested it myself, but it looks like what you described in your question.

Answer (score 0):

all the answers so far would work fine if your programs would actually terminate.
here is a couple ideas you can use look through documentation for more details.

1st - option would be to modify your programs to have them terminate after printing the result message by returning a success code.

2nd - if not possible use forks.

write a main where you make a fork each time you want to execute a program.

- in the child process use dup2 to have the process' output in a file of your choice.
- in the main keep checking the content of said file until you get something and compare it with either success or failure.
  -empty the file.
- then you can make another fork and execute the next program.
- repeat the same operation again.

bear in mind that execute is a command that replaces the code of the process it is executed in with the code of the file passed as a parameter so make the dup2 call first.

Answer (score 0):

When your program returns Success or Fail and continues running, you should kill it as soon as the string passes.

Make a function like

```
function startp {
   prog=$1
   ./${prog} | while read -r line; do
      case "${line}" in
      "Success")
         echo OK
         mykill $prog
         exit 0
         ;;
      "Fail")
         echo NOK
         mykill $prog
         exit 1
         ;;
       *) echo "${line}"
         ;;
      esac
   done
   exit 2
}
```

You need to add a mykill function that looks for the px program and kills it (xargs is nice for it).

Call the function like

```
startp p1 && startp p2 && startp p3
```